# How to assign a file content into a Makefile variable without losing carriage-returns

Tags: makefile

According to [GNU manual](http://www.ecoop.net/coop/translated/GNUMake3.77/make_8.html#SEC80):

> It converts each newline or carriage-return / newline pair to a single space. It also removes the trailing (carriage-return and) newline, if it's the last thing in the result.

But it makes more difficult to use awk without carriage-returns:

```
FILE = $(shell cat $(PATH))
TEXT = $(shell echo "$(FILE)" | awk '/Text/ {print $$3}')
```

So my question is whether there is a way to keep carriage-returns when assign a file content to a Makefile variable, or any smart workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot preserve newlines in the results of the `$(shell ...)` function.

You can of course change your makefile like this:

```
FILE = $(PATH)
TEXT = $(shell cat $(FILE) | awk '/Text/ {print $$3}')
```

Or, to avoid UUOC,

```
TEXT = $(shell awk '/Text/ {print $$3}' < $(FILE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to use awk to extract some lines from a file and import them to the makefile while preserving newlines.

```
LOCAL_INO_SRCS ?= $(wildcard *.ino)
t = $(shell t=$$(mktemp);echo $$t;awk '/^\#if 0 .. MAKEFILE{/{f=1;next}/^\#endif .. MAKEFILE}/{f=0}f' $(LOCAL_INO_SRCS) >$$t )
include $t
$(shell rm $t)
```

And, here is an example of something you can import from the source file:

```
#if 0 // MAKEFILE{

BOARD_TAG = attiny85

# usbtiny hack
MONITOR_PORT = usb
FORCE_MONITOR_PORT = define

#endif // MAKEFILE}
```